# OpenCV+Visual Studio 2008 - Program runs fine in debug but access violation in regular execution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, opencv

I'm working on a computer vision program at the moment with OpenCV in C++. It seems to work 100% fine with a live feed from a webcam but when I tried to feed in a stream from an avi file it started crashing with an "Access Violation" error. I can't see why this would be the case because the only difference between the two is the initial frame-grabbing- the image processing is the same afterwards.

I'm developing in VS2008. The curious thing is that when I place a breakpoint in my main() and debug (F5) the program runs fine. However, when I Start Without Debugging (Ctrl+F5) I get the error.

Has anybody encountered a similar problem or would anyone know why my program would appear to work fine when debugging but not in normal execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suspect uninitialized variables.  Many debuggers initialize all variables, including those that are not.

Comment: Yes, thanks, you're right.

Turns in some instances I would have null pointers and the debugger was pointing them to jibberish, nonsensical values. I don't know why the debugger does this but I've resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing specific about OpenCV, but the fact that it behaves differently with a different source stream, and in or out of the debugger, makes me think it is a timing issue. You could try attachng the debugger after the crash happens maybe.